# A good free book to get started

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I am a fluent English speaker and I wanted a good FREE PDF to get started with. Primarily, I wish to see if my interests in learning spanish will sustain before I buy an expensive book. I have picked up books in the past only to realize that my motivation dips and the books are wasted. So, I wish to first be able to read a good book covering some vocabulary and some grammar before I really dive in. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE!  We're glad you're here.  However, this particular question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. "Shopping recommendation" questions are off topic on the entire SE network, as they solicit multiple, equally correct answers.

Comment: I would encourage you to look at amazon.com for book reviews. You can easily search for free books for kindle (with a free kindle reader available for download), and you can limit your search to Spanish-language books, and by an area of interest, and you can read reviews there, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a book, but a very useful page with online resources is [BBC - Learn Spanish](http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/spanish/).

I don't know if there's any Spanish course such as those offered for free by [Deutsche Welle](http://www.dw.de/dw/0,,4640,00.html) to learn German Language. They have pdfs that you can print, and mp3 to hear also.

Comment: No veo muy motivadora a ninguna de tus ofertas. En todo caso serviría para aprender, pero el OP quiere algo que lo *seduzca* para que se siente motivado a aprender español. Recomendale contenido cultural de tu país, algo que te guste a vos. Porque sinceramente ni siquiera los nativos consumiríamos esas cosas que proponés